# Why is this bash script giving me an error about "missing `]'"?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have to check the existence of the files `dir1` and `dir2`. Then, delete them recursively, else print some message. Here is my code:

```
if [ -d "dir1"] && [-d "dir2"]; then
 echo "directory exists"
 echo "deleting existing files...."
sleep 2
 rm -r dir1
 rn -r dir1
 echo "exisitng files deleted!!"
else   
 echo "directory does not exist"
fi
```

This is giving me an error saying missing expression.

```
./check.sh: line 16: [: missing `]'
directory does not exist.
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Could you solve this issue, @mahesh?

Comment: yes i solved it i was running it fom some different path.!!

Answer (score 7):

This line is not properly written:

```
if [ -d "dir1"] && [-d "dir2"]; then
             ^      ^       ^
              missing spaces
```

should be

```
if [ -d "dir1" ] && [ -d "dir2" ]; then
```

Then you have this:

```
rn -r dir1
 ^
 rn does not exist
```

which should be `rm` and `dir2` becaus you already deleted `dir1`:

```
rm -r dir2
```

Comment: OP also try to delete dir1 twice.

Comment: Thanks, @falsetru, didn't notice that. In fact he was using `rn` instead of `rm`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have:

```
[ -d "dir" ]
```

and **not**:

```
[-d "dir"]
```

Note the spaces. See fedorqui's answer regarding the other problems.

Proposed more robust solution (add more verbose output to your liking):

```
#!/bin/sh

dirs="dir1 dir2" # Directory names may not contain spaces
for dir in $dirs; do
    [ ! -d $dir ] || rm -r $dir || echo "failed to remove $dir"
done
```

Note that your solution with `&&` requires both directories to exist for it to trigger removal. I don't know if that is your intention or not. My solution looks if any of the directories in the `dirs` variable exists and in that case tries to remove them.

Comment: yup....got it worked!!Yes my intention is that only if both files exists then delete the files. Thanks for the proposed solution.

Comment: Using `dirs` like that is not recommended, as it will only work properly if neither directory name contains a space. If it doesn't need to be POSIX-compatible, you can use `dirs=( "dir1" "dir2" )` and `for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do`.

Comment: @chepner: Yeah your right about that, good point. However I thought the use case was simple enough for it to work. When looking at the other answers (and even the question) there is no quotes for `rm` either, and that call would most likely fail too if directory name contains spaces (Best practice: *Don't* use spaces in file-/dir names). I'll add a comment about it though, thanks.